# Return Sitecore item as list of Model

Tags: sitecore-api

I am trying to return sitecore items list from my controller  as list of model type

eg.  `public List<PageContent> Results { get; set; }`

I need to get the list of items in Results.

Using glassmapper this is easily done

```
this.Results.Add(siteContext.GetItem<PageContent>(result.Document.GetItem().ID.Guid));
```

but I need to get it without glassmapper. Any way of doing this?

Comment: Create a Model and initialize it and fill model property in foreach loop

Comment: @GauravAgarwal yes created the model and filled the model but not able too add it in resuts.                            
                            foreach(var res in response)
                            {
                                if (res != null)
                                {
                                    this.Results.Add(res);
                                }
                            }

Comment: var response = results.Select(x => new PageContent
                            {
                                Title = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Document.Title) ? x.Document.Title : string.Empty,
                                Description = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Document.Description) ? x.Document.Description : string.Empty,

                            }).ToList();

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have list of items of type Item in `results` object,

```
ModelName model = new ModelName();

model.Results = results.Select(x => new PageContent(){
    PageContentModelProperty1 = x.Fields["TitleFieldName"]?.Value,
    PageContentModelProperty2 = x.Fields["DescriptionFieldName"]?.Value
}).ToList();

return model;
```